# Ionic StatusBar Leaving Blank Space?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar, ngcordova

Recently, I've been developing an app with the Ionic Framework. Unfortunately, I've ran into a huge issue that I can not manage to fix -- no matter what I try.

For some reason, whenever I utilize the Cordova StatusBar plugin in order to hide() the top status bar, I am left with a ~20px grey bar on the top of the screen.

The statusbar information disappears, but the blank space is still reserved. Any idea as to what I could do in order to resolve this? I'm desperate at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show me your confiig.xml

Comment: share your code first . In <ion-content  use class has header

Comment: <body ng-app="appName">

    <ion-pane>

        <ion-nav-view>
        <!-- App views injected here via app.js -->
        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-pane>

    </body>